# Girar una imagen 10 grados a la derecha cada vez que se haga clic en un botón

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'div.rotateImage1 .elementor-widget-container', function (rotateImage) {
    let currentRotation = 10;
    currentRotation += 10;
    document.getElementById("myImage").style.transform = `rotate(${currentRotation}deg)`;

});
```

Solo me realiza el giro en el primer clic y me gustaría que cada vez que se hiciera clic en el botón girará 10 grados más a la derecha.

Comment: Declaras `currentRotation = 10;` cada vez que entra al método, así que a la segunda vez que entras vuelve a empezar a 10... siempre, cada click, empieza en 10. No es que no funcione, funciona siempre, pero siempre lo pone a 20 (10 + 10). Declara la variable *fuera* de tu método, de esa manera no la sobreescribirás en cada click, y se incrementará correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate que cada vez que clicas, defines `currentRotation` como 10, y seguidamente le sumas 10 más, así que siempre serán 20.
Define `currentRotation` fuera de la función.